# What does Kierkegaard mean by "world-historical"?

Tags: kierkegaard

In part II of C.U.P. Kierkegaard writes a lot about the "world-historical" and how objectivity and speculative reasoning are related to it. I guess I just need a good description of exactly what he means by "world-historical", as I am having a hard time grasping his meaning. Especially when he says things like, "World-historical calculation is done with denominate quantities and enormously large quantities, which by their multiplicity in multiple ways stimulate multiplicity in the observer" (pg. 143).

Comment: The simplest sense would just be "having to do with world history", maybe I'm missing something here though :)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's pretty much it. I think he really means just anything that has happened in time as opposed to the immediate. Thanks!

Comment: The "world-historical" is a reference to Danish Hegelianism. In Climacus's case, it has a negative meaning and is being parodied. The opposite category is the individual -- which is what really matters for Kierkegaard.